# Correct assetic 'filter' syntax?

Tags: symfony, twig, assetic

Where is the correct place to put the 'filter=...' parameter?

I've seen it before / after / in between the files referenced, but I am
not sure if the location makes any difference.

Moreover, is it possible to apply different filters to different files within
one `{% stylesheets ... %}` section?
For example.. to have 'xxx' apply to both files, 'yyy' apply to *only to a.css* & 'zzz' apply to *only to b.css*

```
{% stylesheets filter='xxx'
    'path/to/a.css' filter='yyy'
    'path/to/b.css' filter='zzz' %}<link rel="stylesheet"
type="text/css" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the docs, is should be after file list: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#filters , but it has no importance.

To my mind you can't apply different filters to different files in the same tag.